# How to do a union of two columns and then sort them into a third column in Excel?

Tags: excel, sorting

I'm having the following sorting problem in excel - I have two columns which are sorted and could potentially have some identical values. I want to take the union of the two columns (e.g. A = {x,y,z}, B = {a,b,c}; C = A U B = {a,b,c,x,y,z}) and then sort them (as seen in the prior example).

Here's how it should look like in excel -

[image]

I haven't seen anything on Google or Stack Overflow that has a solution for this problem. What formula can I use to get the above result?

Comment: Why not copy both columns to another sheet as a single column, then remove duplicates and sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first row put

```
=SMALL($A$1:$B$10,ROW(1:1))
```

then copy down.

Non duplicate solution to be added

Comment: That will not skip the duplicates, though.  Look at 21 and 31.

Comment: How can I remove duplicates?

Comment: I figured out a way to remove duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: You should either post your solution as a new answer or edit it in so other people can see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution, the numbers need to start in the second row.  If that is an issue, then slightly modify the first row.  Also, this only assumes at max two duplicates of a number (one in each column).

```
=IFERROR(IF(SMALL($A$2:$B$11,ROW(2:2))=D1,SMALL($A$2:$B$11,ROW(2:2)+1),SMALL($A$2:$B$11,ROW(2:2))),"End of Numbers")
```

What this does is it says "if the smallest number for the nth row is equal to the row above, then find the nth + 1 smallest, otherwise, just return the nth smallest."  The iferror is just to help identify the end of the numbers.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: This didn't help me remove duplicates. But it's just as good a method as the one above. Thanks!

Comment: If you only have a total of two duplicates (i.e. a 21 in one column, a 21 in the other), the final result will only have one "21."  If there is a max number (something greater than 2), then just do nested "IF's" using this portion of the formula:  `SMALL($A$2:$B$11,ROW(2:2)+`**n**`)`